# How to call a variable from one function to another funtion in php using codeigniter?

Tags: php, function, variables, codeigniter-3

My Controller

```
public function forgot_password(){
        $email = $this->input->post('email_recover');
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        $findemail = $this->user_model->forgot_password($email);
        if ($findemail) {

                $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
                $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
                $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
                $config['smtp_user'] = "myemail@email.com"; 
                $config['smtp_pass'] = "password";
                $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
                $config['mailtype'] = "html";
                $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

                $this->email->initialize($config);

                $this->email->from('no-reply@admin.com', 'Admin');
                $this->email->to(set_value('email_recover'));

                $this->email->subject('Reset password');

                $email = $this->input->post('email');

                $this->email->message('<h3>Dear user.</h3><br><br><p>We want to help you to reset your password.</p>. <p>Here is the reset link &nbsp;'. base_url() .'login/reset_password/'.$token.'</p>');

                if(!$this->email->send()){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'There is some error with your email. Please try again');

                }
                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Please check your email.');
                }
        } else {
                    redirect('login');
               }

    }

    public function reset_password(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
            $this->load->view('register/reset_password');
            $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');
        } else {
                    $this->user_model->reset_password();
                    //redirect('login/reset_password ');
               }

    }
```

My Model

```
public function reset_password(){
        $data = array('password' => $this->input->post('password'));
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        return $this->db->update('login_user', $data);
 }
```

Please help me out here. I want to send recover email link to user and that is working correctly. Now when user fills the fields in reset password page, I am unable to determine the email id of that user. Can anybody tell me how to access that email that was entered in a different form.

Comment: you'd have to put it into the second form as a hidden field, or store it some other way (e.g. in the session, temporarily). HTTP requests are stateless. Data doesn't persist between them unless you explicitly make it so.

Comment: You can send him link with his encrypted email id and time limit tiil link active. When he opens the link match that credential with DB.

Comment: How can I pass email to that hidden input field? @ADyson

Comment: I don't know codeigniter specifically, but presumably you can build forms using views? If so it should be a property of the view, which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Using session you can update password. please check the below code i think help you.

Controller :

```
public function forgot_password(){
        session_start();
        $email = $this->input->post('email_recover');
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        $findemail = $this->user_model->forgot_password($email);
        if ($findemail) {

                $_Session['setEmail'] = array('email_recover' => $email,'token' => $token);

                $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
                $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
                $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
                $config['smtp_user'] = "myemail@email.com"; 
                $config['smtp_pass'] = "password";
                $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
                $config['mailtype'] = "html";
                $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

                $this->email->initialize($config);

                $this->email->from('no-reply@admin.com', 'Admin');
                $this->email->to(set_value('email_recover'));

                $this->email->subject('Reset password');

                $email = $this->input->post('email');

                $this->email->message('<h3>Dear user.</h3><br><br><p>We want to help you to reset your password.</p>. <p>Here is the reset link &nbsp;<a href="'. base_url() .'login/reset_password/'.$token.'">click</a></p>');

                if(!$this->email->send()){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'There is some error with your email. Please try again');

                }
                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Please check your email.');
                }
        } else {
                    redirect('login');
               }

    }

    public function reset_password($token=NULL){

        if($_Session['setEmail']['token'] == $token){
            $email = $_Session['setEmail']['email_recover'];
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
            $this->load->view('register/reset_password');
            $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');
        } else {
                    $this->user_model->reset_password($email);
                    //redirect('login/reset_password ');
               }

    }
```

Model

```
public function reset_password($email){
        $data = array('password' => $this->input->post('password'));
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        return $this->db->update('login_user', $data);
        $_Session['setEmail'] = '';
 }
```

This token pass in link and after check token in controller is using url. after update password reset session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to store email id. 
In your forgot_password() function in controller, set a session variable to store email id

```
$email = $this->input->post('email_recover');
$this->session->set_userdata('email', $email);
```

You can use this variable where ever you want. modify reset_password() function in model:

```
public function reset_password(){
    $data = array('password' => $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('email',$this->session->userdata('email'));
    return $this->db->update('login_user', $data);
    $this->session->unset_userdata('email');
}
```